# Table with expandable rows with 'lazy rendering' - angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement  lazy loading on a material table with expandable rows.
load the expanded data only after the row was clicked

example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eaajjobynjkl?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html) for Table with expandable rows.

In my project, from the main expanded table, I call another component inside the expanded-row space, that renders some data (inside the expanded row ).

like this:

```
  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
           <!--another component load  -->
           <p>
              <app-another-table [fromMainTable] = 'true'></app-another-table>
           </p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

The problem is that, by default, the expansion rows content will be initialized even when they are close.
instead, I want to defer initialization until a specific row was clicked, and only the content related to his (the clicked row) expend space will load

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wanted the same in my project. I simply wrapped the component inside a ng-container and added the *ngIf directive as shown below.

```
     <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <ng-container *ngIf="expandedElement === element">
           <!--another component load  -->
           <p>
              <app-another-table [fromMainTable] = 'true'></app-another-table>
           </p>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I must say that In my case the collapse animation did not function properly after making this change. I had to add a new animation and trigger in my ts file that was connected to element that has the *ngIf.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was stuck in this since this afternoon.

Comment: @Neveh did you ever figure out how to get the animation back?

Comment: @Time https://github.com/nevehallon/word-game-V2/tree/220e9d50ff20d6827fa9091ec7de84be68208aab/src/app/components/history-table (link to the files in my project's git repo) This is how I managed to get it working in the end.